# Regex to fetch last numeric value in a line which contains String "VAT"?

Tags: regex

This is my line

```
VAT @5.25% on balance 10% of base value 1995.89
```

I am looking for a regular expression to fetch the last numeric value from a line which contains "VAT" literally.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
/^.*VAT.*[ \t](\d+\.\d+)$/
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/apU350/2/)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, actually I was trying ^.*\b(VAT)\b.*\s*$ regex  but that didn't worked.

Comment: I am very new to this and not getting how to achieve the same in VB script. I tried above regex, the one which you shared but its not working. Please help.